What's the ordinary equivalent of "parked cattywampus"?
I stumbled on the word cattywampus.

What is the origin of cattywampus

where "The trucks were parked cattywampus in the lot." is given as an example.
As I understand it, it means the parked trucks are not parallel to each other. What are more common ways to express the same thing?
Also, are there words that can be used to express "something is not properly placed into the space*. For example, speaking of a single truck that is parked somewhat diagonally(?) in the space (for one truck), is there a word that works like below?

The truck is parked ????.

And somewhat similarly, what is a common word that fits the following instead of "cattywampus"?

The painting is hanged ????.


The painting is hanging askew, not hanged.

You might just about get away with haphazardly or askew for one vehicle in an otherwise empty large parking lot that was carelessly parked across two or more marked bays. But unless there are marked bays, who's to say if a single vehicle is "neatly" parked?

Collins defines catawampus (US, dialectal) variously as askew; awry and going badly, awkwardly, or in the wrong direction.
But in OP's specific context, I suggest higgledy-piggledy (mixed up and in no particular order) is a better known alternative (that's a link to a usage chart showing just how much better known! :)

FWIW, I'd never encountered cattywampus before now, but it strikes me as a tongue-in-cheek derivative of wampum, which I think reflects badly on the treatment of native Americans. So I wouldn't use it anyway. If not higgledy-piggledy then topsy-turvy. But that tends to imply random orientation in three dimensions (including Up/Down) - which can apply with higgledy-piggledy, but doesn't have to.

I may be off, but doesn't it matter if it is about single entity or multiple entities? For example, is the trucks were parked askew idiomatic?

Re: higgled-piggledly, is it particularly British or used generally in English-speaking worlds?

@sundowner "The trucks were parked askew" could mean the trucks all parked square to each other but 10° off from the painted lines; higgledy-piggledy would never mean that. In America it's rare but sure to be understood, not considered dialectal or anything, and I don't know if it's more common in Britain.

An Ngram search shoes higgledy-piggledy (note spelling, Sundowner!) as slightly more frequent in British English, but mot by much.

@the-baby-is-you: I don't see how you can say " In America it's rare but sure to be understood". If you follow my link to the NGrams usage chart, you can restrict it to just the AmE corpus, and it's still the case that  both spellings of catawampus combined represent a tiny fraction compared to higgledy-piggledy.

@FumbleFingers I was talking about higgledy-piggledy because they asked.

@the-baby-is-you: The full OED lists catawampus as slang (chiefly U.S. from 1843), with definition A bogy, a fierce imaginary animal. I had to go to Collins (which labels it (US, dialectal)) to find the "askew" senses. But higgledy-piggledy (around since 1598) isn't labeled "dialectal" - just "origin uncertain", with a note saying "Usually contemptuous" in OED. If the OP wants to be understood by most Anglophones, it's obvious which term to use.

@FumbleFingers That's what I said??

@the-baby-is-you: That's what you meant. Apparently even I didn't understand it, and it was written in my native language! :)

So as a speaker of BrE, you have weighed in the meaning of a word that is dialectical American English.  You even go so far as to say you've never encountered it.  Your answer is not helpful.  You merely suggest another word you do know, in its place.  If you don't know what catawampus means, why are you answering a question about it?   You think it has something to do with wampum?  So you don't like it?  -1
